# Как сохранить и вернуть текст вместе с тегами JS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Такая проблема. Я при клике меняю текст. Далее при повторном клике меняю текст на старый, который заранее сохранил в textStorage. Однако при повторном клике текст возвращается без подсвеченных слов (без тега span). Подскажите из-за чего это? Как это исправить?

```js
let el = {
  text: document.querySelectorAll(".text"),
  btn: document.querySelectorAll(".btn"),
  container: document.querySelectorAll(".container"),
};

let textStorage = new Array(el.btn.length);

for (let i = 0; i < el.btn.length; i++) {
  textStorage[i] = el.text[i].textContent;
  // Исходные тексты элементов сохраняются в массиве под теми же индексами.

  el.btn[i].addEventListener("click", changeBorder);
}

function changeBorder() {
  let i = [].indexOf.call(el.btn, this);
  // Находит индекс кликнутой кнопки среди всех остальных кнопок.
  // this — ссылка на кликнутую кнопку
  
  let selected = el.container[i].classList.toggle("selected");

  el.text[i].textContent = selected ? "НОВЫЙ ТЕКСТ" : textStorage[i];
};
```

```css
.container {
  border: 5px solid blue;
}

.text {
  background: #7e3;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.btn {
  background: green;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
}

.selected {
  border: 5px solid red;
}
.span {
  color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p class="text">СТАРЫЙ ТЕКСТ <span class="span">ВОТ SPAN</span></p>
  <div class="btn">ВЫБРАТЬ</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <p class="text">ТЕКСТ НОМЕР ДВА <span class="span">ВОТ SPAN</span></p>
  <div class="btn">ВЫБРАТЬ</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Прочтите внимательнее про [textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) - он служит только для текста.

> Установка данного значения удаляет все дочерние узлы и заменяет их
> единичным текстовым узлом с указанным значением.

Вам вместо него `нужен innerHTML`:

```js
let el = {
  text: document.querySelectorAll(".text"),
  btn: document.querySelectorAll(".btn"),
  container: document.querySelectorAll(".container"),
};

let textStorage = new Array(el.btn.length);

for (let i = 0; i < el.btn.length; i++) {
  textStorage[i] = el.text[i].innerHTML;
  // Исходные тексты элементов сохраняются в массиве под теми же индексами.

  el.btn[i].addEventListener("click", changeBorder);
}

function changeBorder() {
  let i = [].indexOf.call(el.btn, this);
  // Находит индекс кликнутой кнопки среди всех остальных кнопок.
  // this — ссылка на кликнутую кнопку
  
  let selected = el.container[i].classList.toggle("selected");

  el.text[i].innerHTML = selected ? "НОВЫЙ ТЕКСТ" : textStorage[i];
};
```

```css
.container {
  border: 5px solid blue;
}

.text {
  background: #7e3;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.btn {
  background: green;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
}

.selected {
  border: 5px solid red;
}
.span {
  color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p class="text">СТАРЫЙ ТЕКСТ <span class="span">ВОТ SPAN</span></p>
  <div class="btn">ВЫБРАТЬ</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <p class="text">ТЕКСТ НОМЕР ДВА <span class="span">ВОТ SPAN</span></p>
  <div class="btn">ВЫБРАТЬ</div>
</div>
```